# Expectation and linearity

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a non-neg random variable and define $A_i:=\{i-1\le X < i\}$ for each $i$. I have proved that $$\sum_i(i-1)
I_{A_i}\le X <\sum_i iI_{A_i}$$ holds, but I have issues showing that it implies $$\sum_iP(X\ge i)\le EX <
1+\sum_i P(X\ge i).$$ I thought it was immediate by applying expectation (which is a monotonic operator) to each inequality, but I can't use linearity since the sum is infinite.

How else can I do this?

Comment: $X$ is non-negative, so that $i=1,2,\ldots$. Hence all terms are positive. Then you are always allowed to interchange expectations and sums (due to Tonelli's theorem).

Comment: how would you do this without measure theoretic results, and  just the basics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof not using measure theory is the following:

Define $Y = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} (i-1) I_{A_i}$. This is a discrete random variable with probability distribution $\mathbb{P}(Y = k) = \mathbb{P}(A_{k+1})$ using that $B$ with $B_i=[i-1,i)$ is a partition of $[0,\infty)$.

Hence, again using that $B$ is a partition,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}Y
&=
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} k \mathbb{P}(A_{k+1}) \\
&=
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{i=1}^k \mathbb{P}(X \in B_{k+1}) \\
&=
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k=i}^\infty \mathbb{P}(X \in B_{k+1}) \\
&=
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X \geq i).
\end{align*}
Similar arguments can be applied for the RHS. Collecting, this establishes the result.

Comment: Okay great! Thanks that makes much more sense.

Comment: If you are happy with my answer, please accept it so the community knows that an answer to the question has been provided.

Comment: What exactly is $B$ in your construction?

Comment: $B=(B_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is the collection of subsets $B_i=[i-1,i)$ such that $A_i = (X \in B_i)$.

Comment: Actually the arguments won't hold for the other inequality, if you simply choose $Y=\sum_i iI_{A_i}$. you get that $P(Y=k)=P(A_k)$ and the series $\sum_k P(A_k)$ wont reduce to $1+\sum_{k=1}P(A_{k+1})$ that we need to use the other result. Am i missing something?

Comment: You will end up with $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X \geq i-1) = \mathbb{P}(X \geq 0) + \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mathbb{P}(X \geq i)$; then using that $X$ is non-negative yield the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, so I'm writing this as an answer even though it isn't one.  There is a problem with your inequality because for X with integer values:
$$ \mathbb{E} X = \sum_i \mathbb{P}(X \geq i) $$

(See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Alternative_formula_for_expected_value) for a proof.)

Comment: Thank you! its fixed now